# JS this function issues

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, this

Recently I'm facing this problem please help me anyone. I'm trying to show & hide a div which by this function.

HTML:

```
<div class="question_frame">
    <div class='help'>?</div>
    <div class="help_content">Show & hide this text</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".question_frame").find( '.help' ).click(function(){
    $( this ).find( '.help_content' ).toggle(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a **sibling** not a **child**, use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$(".question_frame").find( '.help' ).click(function(){
    $( this ).next( '.help_content' ).toggle(1000);
});
```

The event is triggered on the `.help` and not on the `.question_frame`. Here `this` refers to the element that triggered the event, which is `.help`.

```js
$(function () {
  $( '.help_content' ).hide();
  $(".question_frame").find( '.help' ).click(function(){
    $( this ).next( '.help_content' ).toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question_frame">
  <div class='help'>?</div>
  <div class="help_content">Show & hide this text</div>
</div>
```

See the working snippet above.

If something is there in-between, you can use `.nextAll()`:

```js
$(function () {
  $( '.help_content' ).hide();
  $(".question_frame").find( '.help' ).click(function(){
    $( this ).nextAll( '.help_content' ).first().toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question_frame">
  <div class='help'>?</div>
  <div class="some">Some?</div>
  <div class="help_content">Show & hide this text</div>
</div>
```

Or alternatively, you can use `.siblings()`:

```js
$(function () {
  $( '.help_content' ).hide();
  $(".question_frame").find( '.help' ).click(function(){
    $( this ).siblings( '.help_content' ).toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question_frame">
  <div class='help'>?</div>
  <div class="some">Some?</div>
  <div class="help_content">Show & hide this text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much :)

Comment: Sir, have some problem. If i have some other div like this then not working.

<div class="question_frame">
 <div class='help'>?</div>
 <div class="some"> Hello all. </div>
 <div class="help_content">2 Show & hide this text</div>
</div>

Comment: @FerozAhmed Try using `.nextAll().first()`, and please don't use *sir*.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but please check it, Its not working on this section.

<div class="question_frame">
 <label class="lb_wd" for="">Choice date  <b class='help'>?</b></label>
 <div class="help_content">This need to show After Click on ?</div>
</div>

Comment: @FerozAhmed What's the problem? Can you update it in your original post please?